# Javascript - if(...) evaluating differently in Firefox and Safari

Tags: javascript

So I have come across a very strange issue in my code whereby equality is being deemed false in safari (despite the variables *genuinely* being equal) whilst in Firefox the same equality evaluation is being assessed as true. After a few hours using debugging tools, alas I arrive here...

I have this simple function:

```
function determineChosenLevel(){
  var x = document.getElementById("level").children[1].innerText;
  return x;
}
```

Then I use it in this place:

```
var level = determineChosenLevel();
console.log(level);
if(level === "GCSE"){
// do some things
}else if(level === "A Level"){
// do some things
}
```

Now I run this code on Firefox with `determineChosenLevel` returning GCSE on Firefox and the if statement `if(level === "GCSE")` evaluates to true and corresponding code evaluates successfully.

However.... on Safari, this is not the case. I add a breakpoint on Safari's tools on the first line of code in the second snippet and the console.log(level) indeed logs `GCSE`, but the computer decides to  evaluate the if statement to false and skip over the //do some things.

The image attached shows the level in the browser debugging tools of Safari. The only glimmer of hope is that GCSE appears to have some strange arrow next to it which may be why equality is not holding, but I am not really sure.

Any help would be really appreciated.

[image]

Comment: Your `level` has a return/newline character in it, that is what that arrow at the end of the string represents. So it isn't going to equal exactly `GCSE`. `trim()` your strings to get rid of leading/trailing whitespace before comparing

Comment: @PatrickEvans Ok this is a bit of relief. How has this been generated so I can avoid it in the future? Why is it the case in Safari and not Firefox?

Comment: That arrow is a line feed symbol.

Comment: @codenoob Can you show the HTML where `level` element is?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The element have a line break, like this:

```
<div id="el">text
</div>
```

Which is always invisible in the output, but in Safari the `innerText` property have the line break on it, and on chrome haven't. To get rid of it, just use `trim()` or replace all instances with `.replace(/[\r\n]/g, "")`

```js
var text = document.getElementById("el").innerText;
console.log(text);
console.log(text.trim());
```

```html
<div id="el">text
</div>
```